# Malformed query exception in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the field_value_factor function in elasticsearch, its the first time I've used it and I'm getting some weird errors.

Here is the search query, the keyword variable is passed to the method the search query belongs too:

```
{"function_score": 
{"functions": ["field_value_factor": 
    {"field" : "thread_view", 
    "factor": 1.2, 
    "modifier" : "sqrt"}], 
    {"bool": 
        {"should": 
            [{"match": 
                {"thread_name": " + keyword + "}}, 
                    {"nested": 
                        {"path": 
                            "messages","query": 
                                {"bool": 
                                    {"should": 
                                        [{"match": 
                                            {"messages.message_text": " + keyword + "}
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }, 
                            "inner_hits": {}
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }, 
        "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
}
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[thread_and_messages] function_score: malformed query, expected a START_OBJECT while parsing functions but got a VALUE_STRING];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "thread_view",
            "factor": 1.2,
            "modifier": "sqrt"
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "thread_name": " + keyword + "
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "messages",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "should": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "messages.message_text": " + keyword + "
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "inner_hits": {}
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That resolved the original issue, but came up with another error: `No function with the name [bool] is registered.`

Comment: I don't see how that could be like that... the specified functions list is just one... the `field_value_factor`. `bool` is the query from the `function_score`. I have edited my post 25 minutes ago and changed something. Have you used the latest version?